# Criterion for bisemisimplicial sets to be a manifold

Tags: simplicial-stuff, manifolds, simplicial-complexes

It is well known that a finite simplicial complex is a manifold of dimension $n$ iff the the link of each vertex is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Are there any criteria for weaker structures? E.g. for simplicial sets? In my situation, I have a semisimplicial set, even worse, a bisemisimplicial set, i.e. each cell is realised as a prism $\Delta^p\times \Delta^q$.

Comment: Any simplicial complex is homeomorphic to the geometric realization of the associated simplicial set.  The same is true when cells are prisms because any prism can be triangulated.